# AOC-LPZCR2 Equivalent RAID card

Tags: raid, sas, supermicro, adaptec

We have just had a 'AOC-LPZCR2 Low-Profile All-in-One Zero-Channel RAID card' fail. Unfortunately, we are unable to source one straight away. Does anyone know of an equivalent card which we could use as a replacement, without having to rebuild the server. The card is based on a Adaptec 4000 model, but I cannot confirm this. It is from a Supermicro server and the motherboard model number is X7DB3.

Picture of the AOC-LPZCR2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is Adaptec 4000. This device formats drives in AMF (Adaptec Metadata Format), any newer controller with same RAID level support can detect logical drives and used as replacement, see complete list and replacement details here:

http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16881/kw/replace%20controller%20amf